# Why my Java code cannot compile? [Java: Generic Methods and Bounded Type Parameters]

Tags: java, generic-method, bounded-types

The following is my Java code and it just cannot compile. I cannot figure the reason for fail:

```
interface Comparable<T>
{
    public int compareTo(T o);
}


class MyClass {
    public static  <T extends Comparable<T>> int method1(T t1, T t2)
    {
        return t1.compareTo(t2);
    }
}

class TestApp1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer p1 =new Integer(8);
        Integer p2 =new Integer(9);

        int result = MyClass.method1(p1,p2);

        System.out.println("result = " + result);
    }
}
```

It doesn't compile and the error is:

```
TestApp1.java:19: error: method method1 in class MyClass cannot be applied to given types;
        int result = MyClass.method1(p1,p2);
                            ^   required: T,T   found: Integer,Integer   reason: inferred type does not conform to upper bound(s)
    inferred: Integer
    upper bound(s): Comparable<Integer>   where T is a type-variable:
    T extends Comparable<T> declared in method <T>method1(T,T) 1 error
```

Comment: You did create a custom `Comperable` Interface, and since the `Integer` class doesn´t implement your own custom Interface(and hence it´s not fullfilling the condition you did create whith `T extends Comperable<T>)` it´s throwing this compilation error.

Comment: That's all my source code for this question. <h1>Integer</h1> has the method compareTo(). Even though i removed 'interface Comparable<T>', the compiling error is still the same. I encounter this question when I was reading http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/boundedTypeParams.html

Answer (score 4):

I happened because  your `method1` method using custom `Comparable` Interface where Integer uses `java.lang.Comparable`, so `method1` will throw exception.

Use only below code:

```
class MyClass {
    public static  <T extends Comparable<T>> int method1(T t1, T t2)
    {
        return t1.compareTo(t2);
    }
}

class TestApp1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer p1 =new Integer(8);
        Integer p2 =new Integer(9);

        int result = MyClass.method1(p1,p2);

        System.out.println("result = " + result);
    }
}
```

Comment: as your advice I removed my own interface, but the error is still the same. I came across this problem when I was reading http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/boundedTypeParams.html

Comment: @ZanderHsu now it should not come, just use `java.lang.Comparable` in place of `Comparable` and see if still you are getting same error.

Comment: Yes. you are right. it passed after adding "import java.lang.Comparable;".